# Retrofit - RestAdapter.create crash

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a problem with Retrofit for my new Android application.
I'm just starting up with Retrofit to see if it is great!

I'm using a public service - which returns some x and y coordinates for trains stations:
http://stog.itog.dk/itog/action/list/format/json

So, I have the following pieces of code:

The train stations - with getters and setters for each:

```
private String name;
private int wid;
private double x;
private double y;
```

Interface:

```
   public interface IStogService {
    @GET("/itog/action/list/format/json")
    List<Train> getStog();
}
```

And in my activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://stog.itog.dk")
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();

        IStogService stogService = restAdapter.create(IStogService.class);
    }
```

Running the last line of onCreate makes it crash. I have no clue why - and the LogCat isn't telling anything good :(
Hope any clever ones out there!

Note: I have added permission for internet in the AndroidManifest

Comment: Add .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL) when building the restAdapter to get more information.

Comment: Edit: I have it set - where can i see the logging tho?

Comment: In logcat, but maybe it is crashing too early to print any log (or maybe it only logs requests)

Comment: The code you have posted seems OK, looks like the problem is elsewhere

Comment: It seems like it only crashes if I have breakpoints? :/

Comment: Any ideas about what else it could be?

If it set this code:
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new          StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);  

Then it works great

Comment: Are you calling getStog() anywhere?

Comment: Yes in a click method below. Ofc the stogService are then made private within the class so i can use elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might be getting NetworkonMainThread Exception. Make retrofit adapters and calls in a separate thread or AsyncTask as android does not allow to make network calls on Main thread.

```
public class Backend extends AsyncTask<MainActivity,Integer,String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(MainActivity... params) {
    try{
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("http://stog.itog.dk")
        .build();
        IStogService stogService = restAdapter.create(IStogService.class);
        // Make calls and store in string

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("O Noes " +e);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String k)
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding gson.jar to libs folder.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: @James Massey: This isn't really a "thank you" answer, although the "I had same problem" at the beginning didn't quite help matters.

Comment: Hmm true. Sorry about that.

Comment: Consider using Gradle.